# How can i render roles from fosuserbundle in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using symfony and `FosUserBUndle`

I have made the simple form and its working fine

But i am not able to render the `roles` defined in `FOS User.php`

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/User.php#L113

if i do

`->add('roles', 'text')` then i get this error

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/symfony/app/cache/dev/twig/86/d9/65467411897d4c5c4ef7c0a4bb1a3d4efd01b5d7b4d913636761fd36ee9e.php line 158
```

Comment: *A little tip for the future* : please provide more details in your questions. Add the revelant parts of your code - not just a single line. Add links by highlighting a text-passage and pressing `ctrl+l`. Add a `.` at the end of a sentence and a `?` for questions in the title. It's always quite hard to understand your intention or reproduce your issues with one-liners like `->add('roles', 'text')`. just my few cents :)

Comment: Now I understand that you're trying to add roles to a user using a form. `text` isn't a valid field-type for user-roles in the `$roles` property. A `User` object holds an `Array` of role-strings or  `ArrayCollection` of `Role` objects. The correct field-type is `collection` or `entity` depending on your implementation. In a controller you can add roles to a `User` object like this:  `$user->addRole('ROLE_REPORTER')`. roles are conventionally being prefixed by `ROLE_` and all uppercase.

Comment: @nifr is it possible that i can use entity for roles but store in database as array  rather than foreign key. i dont want  choices field with array hard coded as given in answer

Comment: Yes it's possible - just open a new question for it please. Something like ... how to store related entities as arrays in the same table using doctrine? And please include a description of the intentional use-case. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roles are stored as an array in database. For example:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:10:"ROLE_ADMIN";i:1;s:9:"ROLE_NEWS";}
```

So you can not render array as a text. Try to use choice option, where 'choices' is your array with roles:

```
->add('roles', 'choice', array(
    'choices'   => array('ROLE_ADMIN' => 'ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN' => 'ROLE_ADMIN'),
    'required'  => false,
));
```

Comment: is it possible that i can use entity for roles but store in database as array rather than foreign key. i dont want choices field with array hard coded